# objective c - resident and dirty memory not getting released after dismiss of collection view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

I am loading a 2X2 collection view which has multiple cells and each cell has imageview.But when I am dismissing this controller the resident memory and the dirty memory keeps on increasing.

I have multiple views in my controller and collection view is one of them and I do addsubview and removefromsuperview to show different views in the controller. Before I dismiss the controller I remove all the subviews including the collectionview from the controller's subviews.

But this does not release the resident memory and after it exceeds 500MB the app crashes after throwing a memory warning.
Here is my code to remove the subviews before dismissviewcontroller -

```
-(void)removeSubViewsOfView:(UIView *)view{        
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [view subviews];
    for (int i = 0; i<[viewsToRemove count]; i++) {
        UIView *v = [viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i];

            [v removeFromSuperview];
            v=nil;
    }
}
```

Also I am using ARC.

Comment: To make it shorter, you can do it like this: `[[view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Comment: The remove is not a problem Gabriele. Actually the collection view memory is not getting released even after I remove it from the superview. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Make sure you set all your `IBOutlets` to `nil` on your views `-dealloc` method
2. If you're using view controller containment, call `-removeFromParentViewController`:

   ```
   - (void)removeSubViewsOfView:(UIView *)view{        
       NSArray *viewsToRemove = [view subviews];
       for (int i = 0; i<[viewsToRemove count]; i++) {
           UIView *v = [viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i];

           [v removeFromSuperview];
           NSViewController* vController = nil;//retrieve your view controller
           [vController removeFromParentViewController];
           v=nil;
       }
   }
   ```
3. It won't generate dirty memory, but it may leak objects if you keep mutual `strong` references between objects, aka. A retains B and B retains A

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Micha . So here is what I did - Some of my UI elements/outlets were not getting released and the memory heap was continuously building up because of that. So I explicitly made each of them nil. Its actually wierd that ARC doesn't release memory even when we dismiss the view controller. But we cant blame ARC for this because its just the automation of reference counting. Finally my problem got resolved. Yay!!

Comment: Yep ARC is a good tool but it doesn't do any wizardry.. so there are sill a few things to do manually.